# Searching through a container vs. saving indices within elements?

Tags: search, data-structures, language-agnostic, resources, containers

I've been working on a few programming projects lately, and I've been running into some issues with managing object lifespans and general resource fundamentals. I'm a self-taught programmer, so this may be a very basic issue that I've just overlooked. One of the issues that I've been having has been related to managing containers of objects, especially in situations where you have a reference/pointer to a single element and you need to remove it from any/all of the containers that might also be holding a reference/pointer to it.

Here's a (pseudocode) example that's I've been struggling with:

```
class GameBoard
{
    Vector<GamePieces> activePieces;  //All pieces on the board..
    Vector<Match> matchList;

    public void scanBoardForMatchingNeighbors();
    public void removeMatchingPieces();
}


class Match  //Represents a group of matching pieces as a single object.
{
    Vector<GamePieces> matchingPieces;
}
```

If I have a GameBoard with multiple pieces on it (something like chess/checkers, or even like Dr.Mario/Tetris/etc.), each piece can be matched with another piece of the same color/type/etc.

When multiple pieces are found to be matching, a "Match" object is created and it internally references the matching pieces. Moving 3 blue pieces together would create a match object that references those 3 blue objects, and moving 6 yellow pieces together would create another new match object that references those 6 yellow pieces. Those matches would then be added into the matchList.

While pieces are matched (and therefore, referenced by match objects inside the matchList), they might be animated, change color, or have different interactions, etc., for some amount of time before they're ready to be removed from the game altogether. However, because they're still on the board in the same 'spaces' they're now being referenced by both containers (activePieces and the matches in the matchList).

However, because these pieces are now referenced by multiple containers, I'm struggling with finding a good way of removing pieces from both. Here's an example of the algorithm that I was considering using for "removeMatchingPieces()":

```
public void removeMatchingPieces()
{
    -iterate through container of matches (matchList)..
       --award points, play animations, etc. for each match in the list..

       --within each match, iterate through each piece..
           ---remove each piece reference from the list of activePieces in the game board.. (which involves either storing indices or using search algorithms)

       --Finally, remove the match object from the matchList in the game board after it's been processed..
}
```

The issue that I've been having is that, while I'm scanning through the list of matches and I grab a piece that is part of a match, I want to both remove it from the list of matches after it's been processed AND remove it from the game board. The problem is, I'm iterating through the match container, so when I want to delete each piece from the game board's activePieces container I can't.

**I spent last night thinking about how to address this, and I came up with two ideas:**

**1.)** Have each piece internally store their own index within the container of activePieces. I'm not sure that this is the greatest idea, as it seems error-prone and a little bit encapsulation breaking.

**2.)** Take each piece in the match, and then iterate through the container of activePieces in the game board while comparing references. If the references match, the objects are the same and the index is the number of iterations used in the loop. What concerns me is that this seems like it could be expensive if there are many matching pieces.

**So what's the best way to 'cross-check' multiple containers of objects references to find the same object so that I can properly delete it (or, depending on the language, pass it over to the garbage collector)?**